# Dynamic HTML Form Generation

Tags: java, html, forms

I need to generate HTML forms in Java. I don't know in advance what fields are needed, those will probably be delivered in XML (i have some say over this). I could use the same input file to handle the form submission.

Are there libs, techniques that deal with this problem? I can't imagine that there aren't, but i can't find a suitable solution.
I looked at XForms, but it seems that there's not enough adoption from browsers.

Any ideas? Much obliged.

( Context: JSR-286 compliant portlet (using Liferay atm) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using XSLT to transform your XML input to your HTML output.
Check this [site](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/08/30/xsltandhtml/index.html) for an example for the XSLT part and [this](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2004k/ctl257/JavaXSLT/Ch05.html) site for the JAVA-XSLT connection.

Answer (score 2):

as already said, XSLT can be used to transform your input to htmlif you got an XML input.

Otherwise, a template engine can be used. i had success with Velocity (from the open source project Jakarta).

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

[XSLTForms](http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms/) is an XSLT-based XForms engine for browsers. Of course, it can also be used on server-side. It's an opensource project.

The corresponding "compiler" will soon be available with technical documentation. It will permit you to customize it and add your own specific behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Alain, but i decided to keep input output seperated under our control (meaning independent form technologies other than xml and xsl). Main reason for this is because of the beta label.